# Will getState always return the latest state after a dispatch call?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

If I have code like this,

```
    dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.ABCD,
        ...newInfo,
    });
    const state = getState();
```

Can I rely 100% on `state` being the latest state? Or is `dispatch` asynchronous and I have no guarantee on whether or not the state has updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  A call to `dispatch()`, by itself, is 100% synchronous.  By the time `dispatch()` returns, the root reducer has been run, the state value has been updated, and all subscribers have been notified.  So yes, a call to `getState()` immediately after `dispatch()` will return the latest value.

The caveat to that is that any middleware can intercept, delay, or modify a dispatched action.  So, the final answer is dependent on what middleware you have installed and how they are configured.

Answer (score 2):

getState() does retrieve the latest value, but if you are not mutating your state (which you shouldn't be, for example with the Immer library), you have to be careful if you set it to a 'state' variable inside your action creator.

For example:

```
let state = getState();
dispatch({
    type: actionTypes.someStateChange,
    newInfo1: newInfo
});
dispatch({
    type: actionTypes.someOtherAction,
    infoDependentOnNewInfo1: state.newInfo1.property
});
```

This will not behave as expected because state as define above will have the old state, since the first dispatch has created a new immutable state that is not referenced by the 'state' variable.